# Gstreamer with Java | WARNING and Failed to load plugin

Tags: java, gstreamer, javafx

I try to launch the gst1-java binder on the Raspberry Pi 3B 
with the latest Raspbian Stretch and latest firmware.

If I launch anything with gst-launch-1.0 it work great, I have hardware 
acceleration (what I want in my java project).

But if I try with gst1-java, I get theses following errors :

```
(unknown:3743): GStreamer-WARNING **: External plugin loader failed. This 
most likely means that the plugin loader helper binary was not found or 
could not be run. You might need to set the GST_PLUGIN_SCANNER environment 
variable if your setup is unusual. This should normally not be required 
though. 

(unknown:3743): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 
'/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstdc1394.so': 
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: 
_gst_value_array_type 

(unknown:3743): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 
'/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstbayer.so': 
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: 
_gst_value_array_type 

(unknown:3743): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 
'/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideo4linux2.so': 
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: 
_gst_value_array_type 

(unknown:3743): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 
'/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstadpcmdec.so': 
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: 
_gst_value_array_type
```

And a lot but I don't want to surchage this post.

Can you help me please ?

I already posted in the google group :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gstreamer-java/g2nBHHrgy-k
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gstreamer-java/_P0SenRWKGU
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gstreamer-java/5b2hK0Ej1PE
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gstreamer-java/1VxT_g41-gI

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's resolved.
I deleted all gst binaries and libraries and reinstall them.

Thanks anyway.

This is the command I used :

```
apt-get install epiphany-browser evince gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gnome-user-guide gstreamer1.0-omx gstreamer1.0-omx-rpi gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x libevview3-3 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0 libqtgstreamer-1.0-0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libyelp0 yelp
```